# Script to monitor window title changes

Tags: notify-osd, music-player

Here's the deal: I use the lastfm package to listen my Last.FM (duh)... And I want to show some notify-osd notifications when a new music starts.

As long the program don't supports it, I want to create a shell script that will monitor the window title of the lastfm player and send a notification when it changes.

What do you think? How can I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the title of an open window using [wmctrl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html):

```
$ wmctrl -lx | grep "last.fm.Last.fm" | grep -Po "(?<=$HOSTNAME ).*$"
Insomnium – Death Walked the Earth
```

Watching the title using this method would require the script to periodically poll for changes, though, which would be messy and inefficient.

A smarter approach would be to wait for some kind of event generated by the Last.fm player. A D-Bus interface or similar API would be ideal, but I don't see any documentation suggesting one exists. As a next-best alternative, you can try watching the terminal output for information on what the player is doing:

```
#!/bin/bash

grabnextline=0
albumart="$(mktemp)"

while read line; do
    if [ $grabnextline = 1 ]; then
        title="$(echo "$line" | cut -d\" -f2)"
        wget -O "$albumart" "$(grep -A 10 "<title>$(echo "$title" | awk -F ' – ' '{print $2}')" ~/.local/share/Last.fm/Last.fm.log | grep -Eo "http://.*\.(jpg|png)" | sed 's/174s/64s/' | sed 's/jpg/png/')"
        notify-send "$title" --icon "$albumart"
        grabnextline=0
    fi
    if [[ "$line" = *ScrobblerManager::nowPlaying* ]]; then
        grabnextline=1
    fi
done < <( /usr/bin/lastfm 2>&1 )

rm "$albumart"

exit
```

It's still an ugly hack, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Which player do you use for list.fm . Many application use dbus to notify events. You would need to catch them in script.

Like following page has a example on how to use catch Rhythmbox song change.

[Trace Rhythmbox track change using dbus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919735/how-to-continuously-monitor-rhythmbox-for-track-change-using-python)